# NLP - Sentence does not follow any of the grammar rule in Syntactic parsing

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, text-parsing

I have grammar extracted from Treebank dataset from nltk library. Now the parser will use these rules to parse the sentence. So for example I have grammar like below:

```
A->B C
B->'b'
C->'c'
D->'d'
```

Now suppose I have sentence like `b c` so the parser will make parse tree like below

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
  |   |
  b   c
```

So like this I have all the grammar from training dataset. Now for testing assume a completely new sentence is there like `"c d"`

Parse tree for above sentence will be

```
  C   D
  |   |
  c   c
```

and  the parser will stop as there is no rule for `A->C D`

So how to parse these kind of sentences because training grammar does not have any grammar like `A -> C D`

So the question is how to parse sentence if it completely new and grammar rule is not present in training data set? I am using probabilistic grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things you could try is to cut varies parts of the unresolvable input sentence off and deduct a certain confidence score, then try to match it with existing grammar. if the confidence level drop below a certain threshold you would simply return a message about not being able to parse and drop this sentence. While in the same time you could log these sentences and come up with new grammars.

This is what I did for one of the personal assistant projects, trying to give an answer to all unseen or even invalid input is virtually impossible.

Comment: Which grammar did you use for your project? Do you happen to know any standard English grammars? Treebank grammar is fine but it is messy.